# How can i transfer my gridview data to another aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Inward.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="pono" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Update" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="pono" HeaderText="pono" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="pono" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="podate" HeaderText="podate" SortExpression="podate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="partyname" HeaderText="partyname" SortExpression="partyname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="flag" HeaderText="flag" SortExpression="flag" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itemnm" HeaderText="itemnm" SortExpression="itemnm" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="indt" HeaderText="indt" SortExpression="indt" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qty" HeaderText="qty" SortExpression="qty" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

inward.aspx.cs

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pono = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    Response.Redirect("Update_inward.aspx?pono="+pono);
}
```

update_inward.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(stcon);
    con.Open();
    String query = "Select * from maxus_in where pono=" + Request.QueryString["pono"];
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pono"].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["podate"].ToString();
        TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["partyname"].ToString();
        TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["itemnm"].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();


}
```

How do i transfer this data and display in textboxes in another page??

Comment: Is your current attempt not working in some way?  What is the resulting redirect from this?

Comment: you can not - the gridview is a view of a data set - just how this dataset on some other page

Comment: It is redirecting to update_inward but throws an Exception--An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: @pranaybrahmbhatt: And have you tried examining the exception to see what the error is?  Don't ignore error messages, they tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Query String or store value in the session and retrieve the value on page load of the next page.

> username.Value = Request["username"];
>   username.Value = Session["username"].toString();

Comment: Tried QueryString